# Query in query in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to achieve a query but I'm just unable to do it.

I have 3 entities here:

Clients:

```
class Client(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Model definition for Client."""

    company_name = models.CharField("Nombre de la empresa", max_length=150, default="Nombre de empresa", null=False, blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Courses:

```
class Course(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Proveedor."""

    name = models.CharField("Nombre del curso", null=False, default="", max_length=200)
```

Consumptions:

```
class Consumption(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Consumos"""

    client = models.ForeignKey('authentication.Client', verbose_name=("Cliente"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, verbose_name=("Curso"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

I want to get a list with the 10 most sold courses for the client that visit the page. I want to show the client the name of the course and the number of consumptions that he has done with that course. In every consumption there is a course and a client associated.

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: What do you mean '10 most sold courses'? Does that mean the 10 courses with the most consumptions? The 10 courses with the most consumptions with that particular client? Something else?

Comment: What you said, 10 courses with most consumptions of the client (active user)

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

**views.py**

```
def my_view_function(request):

   # 10 courses with the most consumptions fromt that client:
   courses = Course.objects.filter(
       consumption_set__client = request.user.client
   ).order_by(
      'consumption_set__count'
   )[0:10]

   return render(request, 'template.html', {'courses' : courses})
```

**template.html**

```
{% for course in courses %}
  <div> Course Name: {{ course.name }} </div>
  <div> Number of Consumptions {{ course.consumption_set.count }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not working, but maybe I can use your code and try to work with it. Thank you !